# Linear recurrence solving for tighest possible big O bounds

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am dealing with the following linear recurrence:

X<sub>0</sub> = 1

X<sub>1</sub> = 2

X<sub>n</sub> = 3X<sub>n-1</sub> + 2X<sub>n-2</sub>

I have proven that this has an upper bound of O(4<sup>n</sup>)

However, I have been asked to come up with tighter bounds for this linear recurrence, but I dont know how to begin this. Does this involve solving the recurrence?

Comment: Do you know how to solve recurrence of this type? It is fairly straightforward

Comment: I think the best constant is $\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2} \approx 3.55$ instead of $4$.

Comment: Do not change your question after it has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Write the solution as

$$
x_n = a \lambda^n
$$

If you replace that in your original expression you get

$$
a \lambda^n = 3 a \lambda^{n - 1} + 2 a\lambda^{n-2}
$$

Which reduces to

$$
\lambda^2 = 3 \lambda + 2
$$

Solutions are

$$
\lambda = \frac{3}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}
$$

So the solution is

$$
x_n = a \left( \frac{3}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{13}}{2} \right)^n + b\left( \frac{3}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{13}}{2} \right)^n
$$

The constants $a$ and $b$ you can determine by setting $n=0$ and $n=1$ and using the conditions $x_0 = 1$ and $x_1 = 2$